# VBA: How to show when more than one conditional formatting rule applies in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Let's say I have three rules for cell `A1`:

- Fill cell Green when the cell value is `>3`
- Blue when the cell value is `>5`
- Yellow when the cell value is `>7`

When `A1` contains 10, all three CF-rules are triggered. Is there a good way to show this? Or to at least let the user know that more than one rule is applied?

edit: Imagine this for a big sheet full of data where the user has to see at a glance which rule(s) got triggered.

I would post this to superuser.com, but I will implement with some VBA code and was thinking that if Excel doesn't natively offer such functionality, maybe there's a workaround with a few lines of code. However, if it's still the wrong site to use, just tell me.

Comment: There is always the option to see all rules for a certain selection. Do you really need VBA to mimic this? It's an option under conditional formatting under the 'Start' tab of the ribbon.

Comment: @JvdV What exactly do you mean? Are you referring to the conditional formatting rules manager? I don't want to see the rules, I want to see at a glance which rules got triggered. So for example, if the value is 10, the cell is one third green, one third blue, one third yellow. If the value is 6, the one half of the cell is filled with green and the other half blue.

Comment: That's going to be really tricky I suppose if you want this to be colors. You could however use adjacent cells to mimic the rules one by one. Either in seperate cells using colors or in a single cell using a text saying which rules apply.

Comment: @JvdV Cells next to it have the same rules, I apply them over bigger ranges. What are my other options? 

Is Excel capable of multi-color cells (that is, 3 colors or more)? Honestly, it's not the most crucial task, but a user asked and so I wanted to look into it.

Comment: You can use orthogonal formats to show when multiple rules have been triggered (however it can be difficult to get more than 3 visual cues to be present simultaneously). For e.g. Fill green when >3, Bold text when >5, cell outlined when >7

Comment: @Tragamor Thank you. I'll have to look into it and then decide whether the benefit is worth the effort.